# Как решить конфликт между SQLite + SQLCipher и YandexMobileMetrica?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, swift

Добрый день.

Есть ios-приложение на swift которое используют sqlite3 для хранение данных.

К этому приложению я прикрутил SQLCipher для работы с зашифрованной базой,
интеграцию делал через cocaopods ( https://cocoapods.org/pods/SQLCipher ). Все работает отлично.

Проблема начинается когда я интегрирую аппметрику от яндекса ( https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-sdk-ios/blob/master/YandexMobileMetrica.podspec ) . После интеграции код дальше функции sqlite3_key просто не выполняется, при этом крэша нет и никаких сообщения в консоль.

YandexMobileMetrica тоже использует sqlite3 + SQLCipher и видимо происходит какой-то конфликт, можно ли как-то это решить?

Код тестового приложения простой:

```
    var db: COpaquePointer = nil

    let documentsPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0]
    let path = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/data.db")

    if (sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        print("open")
        let key = "secret"
        sqlite3_key(db, key, Int32(key.utf8.count))
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT count(*) FROM books;", nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            print("ok")
        } else {
            print("no")
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
```

Comment: У тебя есть какой-то доступ к менеджеру базы Аппметрики? Если ты его выгрузишь/закроешь, сможешь открыть свою базу?

Comment: привет. база данных аппметрики создается при инициализации. я даже не инициализировал библиотеку, проблема появляется сразу после добавления зависимости pod 'YandexMobileMetrica' и pod update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему костыльным решением.
Скачал podspec файл аппметрики и убрал из свойства libraries 'sqlite3'.
Потом указал путь к локальной спецификации:

```
pod 'YandexMobileMetrica', :podspec => 'YandexMobileMetrica.podspec'
```

Если кто-то подскажет менее костыльное решение, буду благодарен.

Comment: напишите им issue на гитхабе

Comment: во первых думаю что это не их проблема. во вторых ранее писал issue в репозитории аппметрики по другим вопросам, ответили через пол года, подчинили еще позже

Comment: ну тогда можете отключить sqlite из своего проекта, раз уж вы его все равно получаете из YMM

Comment: его в моем проекте и нет ( http://rgho.st/7LQCDWZZG.view ). sqlite библиотека вшита в  SQLCipher

Comment: вот именно по этому эпл рекомендует не делать фреймворки во фреймворках